# How to update UI from recyclerview custom listener class onScrollStateChanged?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-mvvm

My CustomScroll Listener class is .

This is separate class

```
class CustomScrollListener(): RecyclerView.OnScrollListener(){
    override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
       //When scroll state reflects need to call updateUI method.
    }
}
```

From this Listener class,how to call below controller class updateUI method.

```
class Controller(activity:Activity, viewGroup:ViewGroup){
    fun updateUI(boolean:Boolean){

    }
}
```

If create an instance of controller class within custom scroll listener class, for that also need pass activity as a parameter. Here Listener class is separate class. Update here how to call this updateUI method within scroll listener class.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an instance of the Controller class to the constructor of CustomScrollListener.

```
class CustomScrollListener(val controller: Controller): RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
       //When scroll state reflects need to call updateUI method.
    }
}
```